# "TypeError: fsevents is not a constructor" - already tried a bunch of solutions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, frontend, fsevents

Upon running npm start, I get the error "TypeError: fsevents is not a constructor".

I ran "sudo npm install", ran "sudo npm i fsevents", tried it with yarn, tried deleting node_modules and package.json, nothing works. Don't know why this is doing this.

https://github.com/LSpire/lspire-front-v2

Comment: Please give more details on how you came about this error??? Did it come up in a new react project or when you tried adding a new library... Give more details please

Comment: Upon running npm start in that project, it gives me this error. Yes, this is a new React project.

Comment: I think it's from how you initialize the react app... Can you try starting another react app using this command `npx create-react-app my-app` It'll show you some scripts to run later to show completion in creation of the app.

Comment: Doing that only creates a yarn-error.log for some reason. I always get these freaking EACCES: permission denied errors whenever I try to install or init anything in Terminal.

Comment: Then you have a different error... this is permission denied, check the directory you're creating your react app, maybe create it on desktop or documents... or if you're using linux, you can chown the user permission or use sudo (definitely not advisable)

Comment: I created it in Documents, and then just created it again in Desktop... neither works

Comment: This is a known issue in Create-React-App, basically you need to remove the yarn.lock/package-json.lock and delete the node_modules folder, then reinstall the dependencies
You should not install npm packages with sudo, that may cause your eacces errors. 
You can try to delete the project locally, reclone it, and do the steps that I mentionned at the beginning.
this is the link to the issue: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6891

Answer (score 2):

```
npm audit fix --force
```

You can try it.

Comment: What does that command do? And why should that help in this case?

Comment: I solved this problem according to it instructed by npm.This command can fix some npm problems. You can google it for more details.